# How can I connect to a server directly from nautilus location bar?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

How can I connect to a server directly from nautilus location bar?

In Windows 7, I can just type `\\Name-Of-Server`
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need to know the IP Address of the server you are connecting to. I haven't tested it with the server name.

1. Open up nautilus (Files) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Type this `smb://IP-ADDRESS-OF-SERVER/` and it will take you to that server directly.

#### Example:

If I wanted to connect to the server with this IP `192.168.0.46` I would type:

```
smb://192.168.0.46/
```

You can also include the folder path if you know it:

```
smb://192.168.0.46/folder/
```

Comment: For FTP servers, you could also enter `ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/folder`. Nautilus will then offer to remember the username/password combination.